# Why is gitk not showing my local branch?

Tags: git, gitk

I'm learning about `git` and is using `gitk` to visualize my history and branches.

I tried `gitk` on a locally initialized repo, and it is able to show both branches that I made properly.

However, when I tried to launch `gitk` to visualize a repo obtained using `git clone`, `gitk` only shows one of the branches.

---

This is what happen:

After I did a `git clone`, I can see 1 branch locally:

```
$ git branch
* experiment
```

So I did `git checkout -b master origin/master` to create my local tracking branch, now:

```
$ git branch
  experiment
* master
```

Now I thought I'm having 2 local branches, so I happily launch `gitk`, however, I can only see one branch:

[image: gitk not showing local branch]

I know of a way to view the hidden `master` branch by doing `gitk --all`:

[image: gitk only show other local branch when use with --all]

But now I'm really curious why is `gitk` not showing the local `master` branch that I'm having here, does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gitk by default only shows you the branch you are on.

It seems that when you launched gitk, your current branch was experiment. Therefore, gitk only showed you commits that lie on the experiment branch. This is the way gitk behaves by default because once you have a lot of branches, the branch names can actually be quite distracting.

`gitk --all` tells gitk to show all branches. At that point, gitk showed you the master.

You can create all kinds of views in gitk and you can launch it to use a pre-defined view. Checkout the "Edit View" menu entry.

Comment: I guess `gitk` is launched with different view parameters in the 2 different places I'm launching it. Thanks for pointing out that I can change the pre-defined view in "Edit View" menu, I can tune to what I wanted to see easily now.

Comment: Is there a way of making the default behaviour of `gitk`?

Comment: Its been a long time since I used `gitk`. You could make a git alias that launched gitk with the --all parameter.

Comment: I have `hist = !gitk --all&` in the `[alias]` part of my `~/.gitconfig`. Typing `git hist` in my prompt runs `gitk --all&`.